# How to use "/// <reference types="bootstrap" />" in browser

Tags: jquery, typescript, bootstrap-5

In a typescript file I have the lines,

`/// <reference types="jquery" />`

`/// <reference types="bootstrap" />`

because I am referencing the jquery and bootstrap from a CDN in the HTML.

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"</script>`

So I use the example code,

`var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), {keyboard: false})`

But I get the error "Cannot find name 'bootstrap'. Did you mean 'Bootstrap'? ts(2552)"

I tried to change to "Bootstrap" but I get another error "'Bootstrap' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.ts(2686)"

So I try to add the import it suggests,

`import Bootstrap from "bootstrap";`

But this results in that exact line being placed in the .mjs file, which gives me a runtime error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "bootstrap". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"." in the browser. In the .js file, it places a "require" which also results in a runtime error in the browser.

If I manually modify the .mjs file and remove the import and use "bootstrap.Modal" it works fine.

So how should I use bootstrap in the browser from a typescript file that results in proper code in the .mjs or .ts files?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After trying many different solutions, I ended up just punting and adding the following line after the reference.
`declare var bootstrap: any;`
I also switched to rollup using 'iife' output format, but not sure that made any difference for this issue.